# how do I get pytesseract to use my trained data?

Tags: python-tesseract

I am a huge python noob, likely messing with scripts too complex for my level (I never coded before besides pasting some R scripts. I just finished learning syntaxes and dictionaries on youtube), but it is more fun for me to learn that way.

I'm trying to get this script to read an image. everything is going fine, apparently, and I get no tracebacks

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng+mtg',config='--psm 6')
try:
    print(text)
except:
    print('Unable to convert')
```

However
in the tutorial I have seem, the guy doesn't use tesseract in the script and runs it from the cmd pannel, and uses a trained font. But I want tesseract to run in my script. So I used pytesseract config to use the mtgtraineddata as well, which is saved on C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata as "mtg.traineddta". I followed the documentation here https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ However, if I write gibberish instead of mtg, it still runs, so i think it is not using my trained data. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Is `mtg.traineddta` a typo or did you save it under that name?

Comment: oh, just a typo

Comment: what's the output?

Comment: it is gibberish, and it is exact the same output if I turn lang='eng+mtg' to lang='eng+mtg' though. if I use a cleaner image it does work. I believe part the reason its output is gibberish is because it was not trained with the right cont

Comment: The problem might be the source image you are giving tesseract, refer to this page as to what pre-processing you should do: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality and if possible provide an example of an image